# В мобильной версии сайта скролл не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

Всем привет.В моем сайте в мобильной версии(max-width:480px) не работает скролл вниз.У меня андроид ОС 6.0 Xiaomi redmi note 3 pro.Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить уже вот как 3 дня ломаю голову не могу найти ответа.
вот ссылка на сайт http://heshimovnotes.com/

Comment: у вас там предупреждение валится, `Treat Document Level Touch Event Listeners as Passive`, ктото тач ивенты ловит

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev спасибо но  у меня ничего подобного не показывает.

Comment: Почему bootstrap не используете?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev это хром 56 на всех сайтах пишет.

Comment: @Alex78191 bootstrap же там подключен если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Ну сетка подключена, но классы из нее не используете. Вы на планшете сайт открывали? у вас верстка статическая и элементы обрезаются.

Comment: @Alex78191 да я не владею bootstrap-ом проста из за сетки и подключил.

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 Мало подключить, надо использовать

Comment: По-моему Kali Linux не для программирования предназначен, а для пентестинга.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev ты посмотри какой какой скрипт это уведомление вызывает, у меня – расширение.

Comment: @Alex78191 я нашел решение спасибо

Comment: Забавно, что вы пишите, что C для вас был ужасно скучным, непонятным и неинтересным, а потом хотите выучить C++, считающийся трудным.

Comment: @Alex78191 это все тесты.Копи пасты.И над контентом я буду еще работать.не принимайте все что там написано в серьёз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было просто так как я использовал плагин Skrollr это он мешал скролить страничку и я добавил в body id skrollr-body и все сработало.решение нашел тут http://ideasandpixels.com/skrollr-cant-scroll-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 0):

У меня не работал из-за свойства `touch-action: none;` в файле сброса стилей.